# get null data if post to struts2 with: Content-Type is text/html or text/plain

Tags: java, struts2

Does anyone know what the reason, My controller action can not get data if i set Content-Type is text/html or text/plain when i post data to that action?
(I using struts 2)

My action like below:

```
   public class APINewsAction extends ActionSupport  {
     private String rowId;
     public String getRowId() {
         return rowId;
      }
     public void setRowId(String rowId) {
        this.rowId = rowId;
     }
     public String onNews(){
      System.out.println("rowId="+ rowId);
     }
 }
```

And i configed my struts.xml like below:

```
   <package name="api_news" extends="struts-default" namespace="/news-api">
    <action name="news"
       class="news.action.APINewsAction"
       method="onNews">
       <result name="input" type="json"></result>
    </action>
   </package>
```

Anyone know?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you post something, show the code.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Also, what content types _does_ it work with?

Comment: I tried to use RestClient to post to my URL:  http://localhost:8080/news-api/news   and param: rowId = 123. I choose Content-Type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  -> in my action can get exactly value of rowId=123. How ever if I choose Content-Type="text/plain", i got value of rowId = null. Why param is null?